# My typescript is working though!! visual studio is showing "[ts] Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type. (parameter) event: any"

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, angular

```
mouseClickedMe(event){
    console.log(event);
}
```

My typescript is working though!! visual studio is showing "[ts] Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type. (parameter) event: any"
Its also compiling the code into JavaScript file but how to recover from this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
"noImplicitAny": false
```

in your tsconfig.json

or

adding `any` to the line that your are getting the error. Ex: `(res: any) =>`

Comment: thanks bro (dont have enough reputation to + your rep)

Answer (score -1):

did this,

```
mouseClickedMe(event: any){
    console.log(event);
}
```

worked....NieeeeCee.